# SQL sorting by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have some problems with sorting products by two columns.
First, I want to sort them by the column sort_order, if it exist, and if not, sort products by item_id field.
And, if there is two products with equal sort_order values, sort them by the item_id column.
I`ve tried to use this statement:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(sort_order,item_id), item_id
```

It works good, but when two products has equal sort_order values, they sorting by item_id desc.
Could you tell me what is wrong with my query?

Comment: order by sort_order ASC,item_id DESC

Comment: it works not quite correct
some products have sort_order field, some are not. And firstly, I want to sort the products that has this field, and if this field is equal for two of them, then sort by item_id field

Comment: You can manually tell the query to sort by DESC or ASC

Comment: can you please post a sample of what you get and what is the expected result. it is not clear what exactly does not work for you.

Comment: This is what I have:
I have 5 products
two of them have sort_order value 1 (for example)
'id 466,465'
One has sort_order value '123 => id 467'

anouther two have this field empty
id 463,464

They shows on the site in the next order
'466,465,463,464,467'
And I want:
'465,466,467,463,464'

Comment: can you post your table data here?

Comment: id |sort_order  
463|null  
464|null   
465|1  
466|1  
467|123

Sorry for this view(

Comment: I`ve solve this problem already. It was with the name of the columns by which I wanted to order my results. And, it seems like this queries ORDER BY COALESCE(sort_order,item_id), item_id  
And order by sort_order ASC,item_id DESC are working good. Thanks you all for helping!

Answer (score 1):

This must be work

```
  select * from table order by ISNULL(sort_order),sort_order ASC;
```